# How to Pivot on single column and create multiple columns from it

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have the following table

```
+---------+----------+--------+------------+------------+
| Country | Provider | Status |  End Date  | Start Date |
+---------+----------+--------+------------+------------+
| US      | P1       |      1 | 1/1/2018   | 2/2/2016   |
| US      | P2       |      1 | 11/12/2017 | 3/11/2016  |
| US      | P3       |      1 | 10/11/2016 | 4/5/2016   |
| US      | P4       |      1 | 5/12/2016  | 9/1/2015   |
| China   | P1       |      2 | NA         | 2/2/2016   |
| China   | P2       |      2 | 11/19/2018 | 3/11/2016  |
| China   | P3       |      3 | 6/8/2018   | 4/5/2016   |
| China   | P4       |      1 | 9/6/2017   | 9/1/2015   |
+---------+----------+--------+------------+------------+
```

Expected Result

```
+---------+------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Country |  P1  |  P2  |  P3  |  P4  | P1 Status | P2 Status | P3 Status | P4 Status | P1 Start Date | P2 Start Date | P3 Start Date | P4 Start Date | P1 End Date | P2 End Date | P3 End Date | P14End Date |
+---------+------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| US      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 | 2/2/2016      | 3/11/2016     | 4/5/2016      | 9/1/2015      | 1/1/2018    | 11/12/2017  | 10/11/2016  | 5/12/2016   |
| China   | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |         1 |         2 |         3 |         1 | 2/2/2016      | 3/11/2016     | 4/5/2016      | 9/1/2015      | NA          | 11/19/2018  | 6/8/2018    | 9/6/2017    |
+---------+------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

can you guys help me pivot this table to get expected output?

P.S. - Don't worry about the NULL columns (P1, P2, P3 and P4), i can just create them in SELECT statement dynamically.

Comment: Where is the table in this ton of data?

Comment: i was having problem while formatting the table
now it's visible properly

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `MAX` function combined with either a `CASE` or `IIF` to achieve similar results in the past. Essentially, you have to manually pivot the table.  The `CASE` or `IIF` is used to only return a value based on the secondary selector (Provider in your case). Then the `MAX` gets rid of the `NULL` values created for the other Providers.

Here is an short snippet to get you started. You should be able to expand it out to build up the table you are expecting.

```
SELECT
     Country,
     P1Status = MAX(IIF(Provider = 'P1', Status, NULL)),
     P2Status = MAX(IIF(Provider = 'P2', Status, NULL)),
     P1StartDate = MAX((IIF(Provider = 'P1', StartDate, NULL)),
     P2StartDate = MAX((IIF(Provider = 'P1', StartDate, NULL))
FROM
     Table
GROUP BY
     Country
```